# New LWC Actions in Salesforce

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

Looks like in the current release Salesforce has made LWC Quick action "Generally available" but the tag that we use in LWC quick actions which is `lightning-quick-action-panel` is still in BETA right? So, is it safe to use LWC as a quick action even though `lightning-quick-action-panel`  is still in BETA from Production point of view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beta simply means that a feature is released for general use, but with some known limitations. It is generally acceptable to use Beta features in production, as most of the time, they work perfectly fine. The only real suggestion for Beta features is that you test them in a Sandbox and make sure nothing breaks when you use it.

Answer (score 0):

`LWC Quick action` & `lightning-quick-action-panel` both are completely different.

**Quick action supports LWC : **  this is a feature already [GA](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_lwc_quick_actions.htm&type=5&release=232) from summer 21.

**lightning-quick-action-panel** :  this is lwc base component just like lightning-card, yes as you said this still in [beta](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-quick-action-panel/documentation).

but you can use lwc quick action feature in prod with out `lightning-quick-action-panel` if you worry about 'eslint' warnings.

nothing going to harm if you use 'lightning-quick-action-panel' in prod unless if you add any complex customization on that.